# Is there a way to record my stats from pool sites?

Tags: mining-pools

I have been mining a few different pools over the past few weeks and I would like to collect my stats that are updated on the pools' pages.  Is there an API or something else I can use to collect this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any open source Monero pool software that has an API, so most pools do not have API's. The only way to get the stats from these pools would be to scrape the data using a web parsing tool, or building one yourself.

Comment: if you plan to go the scraping route there is a great python module called [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) that would make it really easy.

Comment: @kkhugs there are plenty of open source projects that have APIs.  Openstack itself has at least 15.

Comment: @well_then I'll definitely check out Scrapy to see if I can get it to work for me.

Comment: @opticz_akz643 Sorry, I meant open source Monero pool software. I'll edit to reflect.